# Strange behavior when returning a value from an include

Tags: php

I am having a strange issue with getting an array returned from an include. The example taken from the manual shows the behavior I am expecting:

**return.php**

```
<?php
$var = 'PHP';
return $var;
?>
```

**noreturn.php**

```
<?php
$var = 'PHP';
?>
```

**testreturns.php**

```
<?php
$foo = include 'return.php';
 // This is the expected behavior.
echo $foo; // prints 'PHP'


$bar = include 'noreturn.php';
echo $bar; // prints 1
?>
```

My usage scnario gives different result.  I load Zend_Config by calling it with a simple include that returns an array() :

**config.php**

```
<?php
/*
 *      Configuration options loaded in Zend_Config
 */ 
 return array(

 'localDB' => array('serverName' => 'TESTDB',
                    'uid'        => 'TESTUSER',
                    'pwd'        => 'TESTPW',
                    'DB'         => 'TESTDB'          
                 ),
);

// in the app I can call Zend_config somewhat like this ...
$configfile = 'config.php';

// zend_config takes an array as parameter, returned by the included file...
$config = Zend_config(include $config);
```

All is fine. Except now I want to overide this array for test configuration, without changing the file, so I do this:

**testConfig.php**

```
 $testsettings = include_once 'config.php';

 // override the array
 $testsettings['localDB']['serverName'] = "TEST";

 //return the overriden array
 return $testsettings;
```

Now, the weird part. It all works fine when I execute php -f testConfig.php and var_dump() $testsettings.

But if I include this file in a testcase to have orverriden settings value, the result is always a (bool) true, *like the example include shown at top with no return value set*.

I have thought of a few workarounds for this, but was wondering out of curiosity if anyone had a clue as to why it does this.

Comment: I honestly think that using return statements in include files is terrible.  There are better ways to override that array.

Comment: code in last example (testConfig.php) has syntax error.

Comment: "return" conceptually is meant to be used with functions.

Comment: This was like this before, a legacy app that _many_ developpers have come and gone on. I am to add a few unit tests before adding new features. As for the array-returned-from-include, it will be factored out in a function call, I was just going for a quick way to test this thingie with a somewhat isolated environnement.

Comment: @OZ_ What is the syntax error? It passes php -l and runs fine  and returns value on php -f ... ?

Comment: @stefgosselin `include_once 'config.php';` was without quotes in your first edit. Now with quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`include_once` returns `true` every time after the first one. So the line

```
$testsettings = include_once 'config.php';
```

sets `$testsettings` to true if you've included `config.php` anywhere in earlier code.

Comment: Ha! I was shutting down but I think you hit the bullseye my friend! Will check this out tonioght from home, + oned for the quick thinking.

Comment: Aside from the wtf factor of having return in an include, this scenario makes it impossible to use in a reliable way,  Thanks for putting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is not a bool, but a count of the array.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the docs. Check out the section on *Handling Returns* - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php. But basically - don't do this.

Comment: I definetely do not recommend using return in an include, but it is the code I was handed over to deal with. My poker hand for the time being and aside for a few little odd things here and there overall it's pretty clean, I have waded through much worse. As a sidenote, the Zend_Config doc I consulted today gives this same usage example so I presume the fellow that implemented this component just relied on the given example.